# Can write Sublime plugin, which reacts to arrows?

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to know, is it possible to write such plugin for ST2?
Idea: plugin handles special key (e.g. Ctrl+F1)-- after this key press, plugin handles arrows keys special way: it reacts to all 4 arrows and draws "frame" characters in editor.
So on Right key it draws into text "-" char, on Up key it draws into text "|" char (at needed position), etc.

After pressing special key again, arrows work deactivated (arrows work as usual).

Inserting is easy.
I doubt that plugin can handle simple arrows (after pressing special key).
Or is it possible, with what API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe  https://github.com/KonTrax/MultiBind will do what you want.

**Edit**
In short, the plugin sets some setting that defines state. See `MultibindToggleCommand` to see how this is done. It then uses a context entry to use run the appropriate key binding. For that see `MultibindListener` While not completely documented, the example demonstrates how to set a state and use  w, a, s, and d for different key bindings. You would do something similar with up, down, left, and right for your key bindings. I'm not sure why you want to start a plugin from scratch, when the one I posted does what you want. You can investigate the plugin code to see how it interacts with the sublime API. You would bind to the arrow keys like you would any other key binding in Sublime Text.

Comment: It's not good documented, and I don't need a plugin, I need to know about ST api - how to use API to create plugin described?

Comment: I've included a short description, most of which was derived from analyzing the plugin posted.